# python reading csv and while break

Tags: python

[result when enter 1st id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXb8O.png)  [main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gPhH.png)
[result when enter other two id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1mi.png)

when run and enter input(student ID) , it only work when i enter first student id in the csv file. when i enter other two student ID , it shows record are not find.

another problem is , no matter which ans it comes out , the break doesn't work .

please help me , just tell me which part i did wrong .

my CSV DATA：

```
Peter,Tan,S1012342D,89,67,54,78
John,Lim,S1014322H,87,78,86,67
Ada,Ang,S1023456I,54,78,65,54
```

Comment: please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),no one can answer your problem without knowing how you tried to resolve it

Comment: Try looking at `csv.reader` and not `csv.DictReader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
filename='file1.csv'

# initializing  rows list 
rows = []  
choice ='Y'
while choice =='Y': 
  id_input = raw_input('enter student id :') 
  id = id_input.upper()
  # reading csv file 
  with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile: 
  # creating a csv reader object 
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
     # set flag = true if student_id is found else set flag= false
     flag = 0
     # extracting each data row one by one 
     for row in csvreader: 
        if row[2]==id:
          print row
          flag = 1

     if flag == 0:
       print 'Not found'
  choice=input('enter more (y/n)?').upper()
```

make sure to  name the first line of the csv file as first_name,surname,student_id,science,english,maths,sports (as per your requirement).
to make it run continuously put in 'while True:' loop

Comment: Hi, i have try you code, it works . but there is another problem . when i add in while loop. it print multi time which means for this csv data it print 3 result out. can you edit and put in while loop also ? thank you so much

Comment: added a loop for continuous checking unless user enters 'N'